# jQuery qTip with bxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider, qtip

I'm trying to place annotations using qTip on images in bxSlider. By default, qTip and bxSlider seem to work pretty well together, but I have it set up so that qTip shows by default instead of on mouseenter. When I go to the next slide, the tip for the previous slide stays in place. This is what I have right now:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03e6o4d2/)

**bxSlider**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    swipeThreshold: 100,
    oneToOneTouch: false,
    easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.060, 0.500, 1)',
     onSliderLoad: function(){
  },
  onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    $('.qtip').hide();
},
  onSlideAfter: function($slideElement){
  jQuery('video').trigger('play');
  $('.qtip').show();
  },
}).on('click', function(){
    slider.goToNextSlide();
});

  });
```

**qTip**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('area[alt]').qtip(
    {
     hide: false,
        content: {
            attr: 'alt' // Use the ALT attribute of the area map for the content
        },
         show: {
        ready: true
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'caption'
        }
    });
});
```

How would I go about targeting and showing only the tips for the current slide?

Comment: Could you create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

I got the tip to show on only the slide it belongs to. I think it's how your'e callbacks are being called. There's a link in the image map that did nothing so I placed `preventDefault()` within your video trigger ( which does nothing at the moment.) I attempted to separate your events more evenly since there's a lot of stuff going on during a slide transition. Here's the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/kfauzp5g/)**
Btw there was an open `figure` end tag and an open `li` tag I commented them out. Sorry  I had to change names, it helps me to think faster. Let me know if you need more info.

## Update 1

I just thought of something, the qTip was popping up on the second slide and I originally thought it's a call back problem. Instead of the qTip not hiding it was probably stuck in that state because of those open `figure` and `li` end tags actually functioned as the end tags for both images and slides. So essentially instead of 2 slides you had one big slide so as far as qTip was concerned, the cat image was part of your image map.

## Update 2

I noticed my Fiddle keeps on breaking. Upon further examination I noticed the bx external files are hosted on your domain and also all of the URLs are not HTTPS which jsFiddle doesn't like. I am using [jsDelivr for bxSlider](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js), [CDNjs for qTip](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.2.1/jquery.qtip.min.js), and [Microsoft for jQuery](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js)

## HTML

```
    <ul class="bxslider">
    <li class="slide">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/vLRGSyz.png" usemap="#savage">
            <map id="savage" name="savage">
                <area shape="circle" alt="Adam Savage" title="Savage Twins" coords="330,131,32" href="#" target="_self" />
            </map>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        <figure>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wQAnzvl.jpg" alt="cat" title="feline">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <!-- </figure>
   </li>-->
</ul>
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bx = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        swipeThreshold: 100,
        oneToOneTouch: false,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.600, 0.060, 0.500, 1)',
        /*     onSliderLoad: function(){},*/
        onSlideBefore: function ($ele, from, to) {
            $('.qtip').hide();
        },
        onSlideAfter: function ($ele) {
            jQuery('video').on('play', function (eve) {
                eve.preventDefault();
                $('.qtip').show();
                this.on('click', function () {
                    var that = this;
                    bx.goToNextSlide(this, that[from], to);
                });
            });
        }
    });

});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('area[alt]').qtip({
        hide: false,
        content: {
            attr: 'alt' // Use the ALT attribute of the area map for the content
        },
        show: {
            ready: true
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'caption'
        }
    });
});
```

## Update 3

### Untested

```
/* Use: $(document).on('click', this, event handler); 
/* instead of $(this).click(event handler);
/* Create an .ON event handler */
$(document).on('click', '.area', function(event) {
    $(this).qtip({                // Bind qTip inside the .ON event handler
            overwrite: false,     // prevents qTip from being overridden
            content: $('.area'),  // area.area as content element
                 attr: 'alt',     // area.area[alt] as content
                 show: {          // SHOW qTip event when...
                    ready: true, /* ...when qTip is loaded, and READY */
                    event: event.type /*...when the EVENT (which is 'click') happens to THIS(which is .area) */
                 },
            },event); /* Pass the live event to qTip */
});
```

Details: http://qtip2.com/guides#integration

**P.S.** Assign the `area` element `.area`

**Example**

`<area **class="area"** shape="circle" alt="Adam Savage" title="Savage Twins" coords="330,131,32" href="#" target="_self" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The tip is hidden when leaving the slide, but when returning to the slides a second time, the tip doesn't show by default as it does when viewing the slides the first time. Also, I can't navigate the slides by clicking anymore.

Comment: The tip is actually still there but it reverts to mouseover and the positioned circle from the image map has moved. You can find it by scanning the image with the mouse. It should change to the pointer and the tip will activate. bxSlider is versatile but it has a tendency to display and reposition images (this behavior is noticeable if you have portrait images in horizontal mode.)  As for navigation, do you mean not at all? Or by tapping the image? If the latter, then you could do... I'll return shortly, I'm running out of characters............................................................0

Comment: I just mean when clicking/tapping the image. I'm not having issues with the target area repositioning, but I'm also using maphilight. I was thinking there had to be some way to target the active slide and only call qtip on that slide, but I haven't figured out how exactly to do that.

Comment: Please see Update 3 ▲

Comment: It's meant to replace the qTip code not to be added on.  It's untested, so adjustment is needed. When I have more time, I can adjust, I'm at work atm.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I replaced the qTip code with the updated code. I'm trying to get it working right now, but nothing so far.

Comment: Ok, to clarify, you wanted:  1. bxSlider to move on a click anywhere on the image   2. qTip to appear when loaded.   3. a new qTip appears and the old disappears when bxSlider advances to the next slide.  I got 3 images in this new version, but only the first 2 appear but the 3rd slide the qTip doesn't work. I think it's because it's a smaller image than the other two.  Anyways, this should definitely help you. [DEMO](http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/bxq.html)

Comment: My bad, The previously posted DEMO was the wrong URL, here's the working [DEMO](http://arcx.s3.amazonaws.com/bxq.html)   Btw, qTip is slow so expect a big lag for qTip to appear.